# Assembly.CreateInstance(): how to enforce Interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, .net-assembly

I have a dll that I want to load during runtime. I use Assembly.Load(byte[]) and .CreateInstance() of the loaded assembly.

**In this assembly, I have an Interface IAnimal and a Cow that implements this interface:**

```
namespace DynamicLoading
{    
    public class Cow : IAnimal
    {
        public string GetName()
        {
            return "This is cow";
        }
    }

    public interface IAnimal
    {
        string GetName();
    }
}
```

**I use a console application to testload this:**

```
namespace DynamicLoading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] assemblyStream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Cow\Cow.dll");

            var cow = Assembly.Load(assemblyStream);

            //Returns null: it is not able to cast from Cow to IAnimal
            var newCow = cow.CreateInstance("DynamicLoading.Cow", false) as IAnimal;

            Console.WriteLine(newCow.GetName());                

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public interface IAnimal
    {
        string GetName();
    }
}
```

I can instantiate a new instance of Cow perfectly fine, but I can't seem to enforce the IAnimal interface (which I have created both in my test project and in the dll project). **Cow from the dll doesn't want to be casted to IAnimal from the testclass.**

How do I call the methods on Cow, such as GetName()?

Cheers guys!

Comment: Where is `IAnimal` defined?

Comment: so you are getting an error on this line "var newCow = cow.CreateInstance("DynamicLoading.Cow", false) as IAnimal;" ?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe As you can see, it is defined both in the test application and in the class library.

Comment: @MauricioGracia I'm not getting an error, because I'm using the 'as' keyword. This returns null if casting fails.

Comment: so you are getting null i guess ;-) since that is not mentioned in the question

Comment: @MauricioGracia Yes, I'm getting null. It's mentioned in the comment in the code though :-) If I just directly cast by using (IAnimal)cow, I get following runtime error: Unable to cast object of type 'DynamicLoading.Cow' to type 'DynamicLoading.IAnimal'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You interface in `Cow.dll` is NOT the same as your interface in the other assembly. **Regardless** if it's the same interface with the same name in the same namespace.

What you need to do is to define the interface in a "common" place, which is visible by both `Cow.dll` and your program assembly:

```
- Animals.Common.Dll
    - interface IAnimal

- Animals.Cow.Dll
    - References 
       - Animals.Common.Dll
    - class Cow: IAnimal

- Animals.Main.exe (Console Application)
    - References
       - Animals.Common.Dll
    - class Program
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two different interfaces, even though they have the same [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), they differ in their [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as they belong to two different assemblies.

Use a single definition of the `IAnimal` interface in some shared assembly which is referenced by both projects.

If you are looking to do this sort of thing regularly (dynamic loading of types), take a look at [MAF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which was designed for creating addins.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define the interface in multiple places, the version implemented in your DynamicLoading library isn't the same as the version in your class library.

Create one version of it in a 3rd assembly and reference that from both the console and DynamicLoading assemblies.

E.g.

Assembly DynamicLoading.Core
IAnimal

Assembly DynamicLoading.Cow - Reference DynamicLoading.Core

Consoe Application - Reference DynamicLoading.Core

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note is that every interface is distinct. You've defined two interfaces that *only happen to* have the same shape. They are still two different interfaces.

There are a few ways to solve this, depending on the structure of your application and what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

**One approach** would be to have your Cow assembly have a **reference to your main assembly** and have Cow implement the IAnimal interface from there:

```
namespace Plugin
{
    public class Cow : MainAssembly.IAnimal { }
}
```

**Another approach** would be to continue down the path you have, amd write a **proxy implementation of IAnimal** that uses reflection over an object.

```
internal class AnimalProxy : IAnimal
{
    private object _target;
    public AnimalProxy(object target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        //probably want to add error handling
        return _target.GetType().GetMethod("GetName").Invoke(_target) as string;
    }
}
```